# JSP linking with Java Servlet BackEnd Code

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, exception, servlets

I am trying to link my Jsp page with my servlet but I'm getting this error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet ImageServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered`
```

Below is my Servlet code :

```
package servlet;

@Component("ImageServlet")    
public class ImageServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Autowired
    imageDA imageda = new imageDA();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    byte[] thumb ;// get the thumb from the user entity

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int generatedDocId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("generatedDocId"));
      try{
          rs =  imageda.getAllImage(generatedDocId);
       if(rs.next()){
           thumb = rs.getBytes("IMAGE");
       }
       }catch(SQLException ex){
           ex.getMessage();
       }
        String name = "images";
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.setContentLength(thumb.length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + name+ "\"");

        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(thumb));
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There are errors in reading/writing image stream "
                    + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and this is my XML code linking to my viewData.jsp JSP page :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/viewData.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Edited, here is my full version of XML codes. I use most of them for my Request.getPart(), tried to configure XML for spring but it doesn't work.Thanks for helping

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/projectAddData.jsp</jsp-file>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UploadFile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/projectAddData.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadFile1</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/addClaim.jsp</jsp-file>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>UploadServlet1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UploadFile1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/addClaim.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadFile2</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/addInvoice.jsp</jsp-file>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UploadServlet2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>UploadServlet2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UploadFile2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/addInvoice.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/viewData.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <!-- The path to your main spring xml file, for example: /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml -->
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is telling you that although you intend to use spring, the `ApplicationContext` can't be loaded due to the absence of a required listener configuration. Spring needs to know the path to your main bean config file, and the missing listener is what it uses to find that information.

Add this to your web.xml (as a child of the root `<web-app>` element, and your web app will start (or at least make it past the error you're getting now).

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <!-- The path to your main spring xml file, for example: /WEB-INF/spring-config.xml -->
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: it is the same as previous error message

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet ImageServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered`

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? What is your servlet container? Also, please post your web.xml.

Comment: I dont really know what version i am using though , i am new to spring sorry. This is all the codes in my XML files.

Comment: Did you restart your container after making the web.xml change?

Comment: Yes i even rebuild and restart the computer and it doesnt work as well :/